# MSSQL 2008: JDBC URL database selection

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

`Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2`.

Created login user.

Default database is set to `'master'`.

Created a database named `'slave'`.

Use `JDBC` URL `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=slave`

All operations performed with this URL are going to the `'master'` database not `'slave'`.

Is there a reason this URL is not overriding the default database? Is it based on the User Mapping?

Comment: your user has rights on the new created database ?

Comment: Are you allowed to connect to that database with the user you use?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a connection code : - see any differences ?** 
- for me it works well

```
public void connectDB()
{
    try
    {
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DBNAME;user=user;password=pass";
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        System.out.println("Database connection = "+con );
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println( "Error connecting to database.  Error: "+e.getMessage() );
    }

}
```